# tools:layout_editor_absoluteY not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I try to design a layout using android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout, from android studio I can see the preview is good but when I built and  run in phone the preview is showing one after another that i never want.

my layout design: 
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context="co.gakkmedia.videoapps.DetailsViewActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/video_preview_01"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Arraw"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="166dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"

        android:textColor="@color/white"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="09.45.05"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="166dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="291dp"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2016"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="200dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5 sections"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="200dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="101dp"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add to MyPlaylist"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="243dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="112dp"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `layout_editor` attributes are only used for the editor preview and have no effect on the final layouts. You should position your elements using the `ConstraintLayout` specific attributes.

Comment: Than  what are the benefit of  using ConstraintLayout.

Comment: There are plenty of benefits, but you are not using the `ConstraintLayout` capabilities, you are just positioning the views absolutely and it's not working because those absolute positioning values only work for the editor preview. For instance, you should use `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf=”@id/videoView”` on the year `TextView` if you want it to always be positioned under the _videoView_ `ImageView`

Comment: What is the benefit of positioning views only in the editor preview if it doesn't effect the final layouts?

Comment: Sometimes it can be useful for giving you a hint of how a certain view will be positioned, when the final view position is calculated dynamically. It's only meant to be used for mocking purposes.

Comment: Could someone add a line with a such an example? It is not clear from the answer what the solution is.